# How to download a youtube playlist with numbered prefix via youtube-dl?

Tags: command-line, youtube, youtube-dl

I have a Youtube playlist, I want to download it but I want youtube-dl to name the files like 1-{name}, 2-{name}, ... n-{name} in order to be able to watch them in the same sequence as original Youtube playlist. In other words I need my downloaded videos to be prefixed with numbers. How can I do that?

Answer (score 154, accepted):

The best solution I found is:

```
youtube-dl -o "%(playlist_index)s-%(title)s.%(ext)s" <playlist_link>
```

Comment: What is the difference between `%(playlist_index)s` and `%(autonumber)s`?

Comment: @Flimm autonumber uses the number in your download queue, if you restart the download it will be reset. playlist_index uses index of video in playlist and is a better option if you want to stop and resume your download later.

Comment: Any idea on resolving when playlist index has been changed overtime? I already have alot of downloaded videos but their index is messed up. I don't wish to rename each one of them individually.

Comment: I would even go as far as: `%(playlist_index)02d` for playlists 10-99 items long.

Comment: @TomaszGandor Exactly what I was looking for! Though it do add `0` if more then 9 items, I want to have `0N` for conformity :)

Answer (score 20):

I think using

```
youtube-dl --auto-number url
```

will do it.

Comment: This is grate, Only one single issue and that's it messes with the names and replace a part of their names with a number. I fixed my issue myself by getting the main idea from your answer.

Comment: @ImanMohamadi Could you please post what you did to fix the issue you mentioned?

Comment: @IgorStoppa I've already added it as an answer my self and choose it a the best solution. see above.

Comment: "WARNING: --auto-number is deprecated. Use -o "%(autonumber)s-%(title)s.%(ext)s" instead."

Answer (score 17):

Use the `-o` option with `playlist_index` and the format `<n>d` like this:

```sh
youtube-dl -o "%(playlist_index)02d - %(title)s.%(ext)s" PLaPV8TkYEUV05rhlfVKXKqxvTkQ_3Tqek
#                               .
#                              /|\
#                               |
```

Comment: better replace "2d" with "02d" to get e.g. "01 - title" instead of " 1 - title" names.

Comment: @atmin - `2d` does that already.

Comment: it didn't for me, `youtube-dl --version` → `2018.12.09`

Comment: It didn't for me either. My youtube-dl version is 2019.06.27. Using "02d" worked.

Comment: I am sharing [an youtube-dl config](https://bitbucket.org/sergio/dotfaster/raw/c1ad20072bc4d2c7f63a094b299dffaae28b7494/youtube-dl.config) file with interesting options including this one

Comment: @SergioAraujo, that file is not available right now.

Answer (score 10):

Please use the below link to download playlist in numbers in increment at first followed by title of the content

```
youtube-dl -cio '%(autonumber)s-%(title)s.%(ext)s' 'Paste your playlist link'
```

Comment: How is this answer any better then the accepted answer?

Comment: Try it out and check which is best

Comment: Actually, he can check the man page and see what those options do. As I will

Comment: c: force resume download -- i: ignore errors (like unavailable video) -- o: output location

Answer (score 3):

excellent! but it leaves you with a file  called 00001nameoffile
so run:

> rename 's/000//g' *

afterwards
to get 01,02,03 etc
For this line below

> youtube-dl -cio '%(autonumber)s-%(title)s.%(ext)s' 'Paste your playlist link'

or as one line:

> youtube-dl -cio '%(autonumber)s-%(title)s.%(ext)s' url ;  rename 's/000//g' *