# youtube-dl - Download playlists into corresponding directory, and number the videos in the playlist

Tags: youtube, youtube-dl

I want to download two series of playlists from this channel: https://www.youtube.com/user/mathdude2012/playlists

The channel has a "Biology" series of playlists and a "Biochemistry (by chapters)" series of playlists. Essentially, I want to make two directories "Biology" and "Biochemistry" that contain subdirectories that bear the name of the playlists in the series with the corresponding name on the channel. Additionally, I would like for the videos to be in order, so each video in a playlist has its index before the title and URL section of the file name. How can I accomplish this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think that is covered by this answer already: https://askubuntu.com/questions/694848/how-to-download-a-youtube-playlist-with-numbered-prefix-via-youtube-dl

Comment: That's one part of what I wanted. The other part was making a directory for each playlist and downloading the playlist into that directory. And do it for multiple playlists in a series. I guess I can do it manually. It's a bit tedious, but less so than having to number each video manually, so thanks!

Comment: Something like `-o %(playlist_title)s/%(playlist_index)s-%(title)s.%(ext)s`